# How to rank array digits in Python

Tags: python, ranking

```
a = [7, 3, 5, 2]
```

Need a program to Ranked this array values in descending Order.
I tried different logics for this but failed to meet the final result.

Comment: Please explain *rank the array values by descending Order*

Comment: [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

Comment: *I tried different logics for this but failed to meet the final result.* **Add what you tried** Also add **What the final result should look like**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.sort(reverse=True)
```

Is this what you mean?

Input: `a = [7, 3, 5, 2]`

After running the code above:

Output: `a = [7, 5, 3, 2]`

Comment: yes that is the required output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
a = [7, 3, 5, 2]
b = sorted(a, reverse=True)
[b.index(i) for i in a]
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: not me who downvoted, but this would run into problems if there is duplicate values?

Comment: need this output [7, 5, 3, 2]

Comment: @ChristianSloper No, it would rank ex aequo. e.g. `[7, 3, 7, 5, 2]` would give `[0, 3, 0, 2, 4]`

Comment: @muhammadabrar then please explain, this is not a rank